# Как мне принять post запрос когда параметры могут быть разные

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется на сайте большой список строк с 8-ю различными колонками, т.е.

```
<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
<td>data3</td>
<td>data4</td>
<td>data5</td>
<td>data6</td>
<td>data7</td>
<td>data8</td>
</tr>
```

Мне необходимо делать выборку из базы только определенных строк, я знаю как принять и обработать post запрос если при post запросе значения полей указаны все, а как мне принять и обработать post запрос если поля могут быть всегда разные? Например:

при поиске на сайте указывается 8 параметров, по которым может быть выборка и соответственно те поля, которые пустые (т.е. не указаны значения) должны игнорироваться при запросе SELECT. 
Всё что мне приходит в голову так это составить множество условий(по другому нет знаний)

Подскажите пожалуйста как сформировать запрос к базе данных(SELECT) с наличием только тех полей, по которым пришли данные из post запроса.

Comment: Когда все значения приходят как запрос выглядит-то хоть? Это приходят названия полей или чаво?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, сейчас попробую сформулировать... у меня идет выборка по пользователям, т.е. если я укажу страну пользователя то идет выборка только по стране, а если я укажу и страну и регион то уже по двум параметрам идет выборка, а вот таких разных параметров 8 разных и каждый запрос может иметь различные параметры. На обработчик приходят и названия полей и их значения, но названия полей и значения приходят все имеющиеся, только если я выберу только одно значение, например страну то остальные поля придут пустыми но их тоже нужно как то обработать. По другому не знаю как объяснить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае будет примерно как-то так:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `something` FROM `table` WHERE ';

$i = 0;
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
    if (!empty($val)) {
        if ($i != 0)
           $sql .= ' AND ';

        $sql .= '`'.$key'` = "'.$val.'"';
        $i++;
    }
}
```

То есть проходим пост массив, если значение не пустое, то добавляем условие. И притом, если это не первый проход - добавляем `AND`.... Ну или `OR` или что вам необходимо.

---

Хотя, на самом деле, в начале лучше отсеять пустые значения через фильтр, типа:

```
$test = ['test1' => 111, 'test2' => '', 'test3' => '', 'test4' => 'sdfsdf'];

$postVars = array_filter($test, function($el){
    return !empty($el);
});
```

где `$test` это `$_POST`, т.е. те данные, что пришли с POST запроса.

А затем как раз делать цикл для запроса, как написано выше.

Ну и конечно тот запрос выглядит очень просто, в смысле подвержен SQL инъекциям, поэтому вы должны сделать его, но на основе подготовленных выражений. Надеюсь вы знаете что это и сможете подставить значения сами.