# Как искать по LIKE по нескольким значениям?

Tags: php, sql, select, pdo

Не знаю даже как правильно задать вопрос. Вообщем есть запрос, с поиском (like) по таблице. С одним значением у меня нет проблем. А вот до меня никак не может дойти, как искать в этом запросе по нескольким значениям. Вот что я имею ввиду:

Есть такой запрос

```
SELECT          *
FROM            `table_text`
WHERE           `table_text`.`text`
LIKE                                        :text;
```

Он ищет определённое значение. Но после я пытаюсь составить запрос, который будет искать несколько значений, правда пока что не представляю как это реализовать. Так как у меня значения из массива, а их количество не всегда одинаковое. Т.е. в этот раз значений 5, в другой их 2, в следующих их может быть вообще 20 и т.д. Поэтому не получается у меня написать запрос примерно так:

```
SELECT          *
FROM            `table_text`
WHERE           `table_text`.`text`
LIKE                                        :text1
AND             `table_text`.`text`
LIKE                                        :text2
// и т.д.
```

Посоветуйте выход. А то сам не представляю как это реализовать.

Comment: думаю вам надо сделать по аналогии http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600378/191482  ..только ограничение по пустоте не нужен...... и скорее не `AND` а `OR` нужен

Comment: Хотелось бы без костылей. Слишком не красиво получится.

Comment: ха.........а вы хотите с динамическим количеством полей  сделать запрос в одну строку? ну удачи.

Comment: `$arrayData = ["yo1", "werui", 'testValue'];
$columnName = 'text';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM \`table_text\` WHERE \`$columnName\` = '";

$sql .= implode("' AND \`$columnName\` = '", $arrayData)."'";
echo $sql;`

Comment: @dgdhsk Генерация динамического запроса - это не костыль, а обычная практика. Существуют даже специальные решения для облегчения задачи построения таких запросов.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал выгрузить шаблоны во временную таблицу. После чего запрос становится простым и понятным. И можно реализовывать логики достаточно гибкие - и все шаблоны сразу подходят, и хотя бы один, и не менее 2, и строго 3, и наоборот, не подходят не более 2...

Comment: Я думал об этом варианте, но сразу его откинул. В sql, есть ли такой метод, который бы работал с перечислением того, что должно лежать в лайке? Что-то вроде через пробел.

Comment: Нет таких "методов". А почему откинул?

Answer (score 0):

Так можно просто

```
Select * 
from table_text
join table on table_text.text like '%' + table.text2 + '%'
```

где table будет содержать весь Ваш список значений